# Ubuntu 14.04 + Windows 8.1 Grub not showing (Boot-repair didn't work)

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, boot-repair

Have been using Ubuntu 14.04 + Windows 8.1 for a quite a while now and everything was ok. Yesterday I decided to clean up my ubuntu system with Ubuntu Cleaner Computer Janitor. I did already several times on this same system with no problems. So I've cleaned everything I was offered. There were no signs of problems during this process. Then I rebooted to Ubuntu again and this first reboot was also alright. Then in the evening I rebooted to Windows and at the night time there supposed to be my scheduled (Acronis) system backups running. So this morning I see my windows system freezed, I reboot and I don't see any Grab loader, just Windows system loading and no choice.

So I've downloaded `boot-repair-cd` and created boot usb-drive. Booted from it successfully and run through all the process of *Recommended repair*. There also seemed to be no problems with that but nothing has changed after it. Still only Windows loading with no choice.

So here is [my log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23850068/)

Comment: try to boot from ubuntu live DVD,then run this commands in terminal #sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sda replace sda with your current device then run #grub-install /dev/sda after that you should back to your grub

Comment: @Ccunlimited, I've solved my problem. See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this in the end of my log file

> For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command
>   in an admin command prompt: bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path
>   \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi

So I've tried it and it worked. 
But I'm still curious what have happened and how I can prevent it from happening again...

Comment: Good work happy for you ^_^